# php console run process and give it input

Tags: php, subprocess

app1:

```
./app1

console output:
app1>please give me the generated key:
waiting for input:
```

how to run app1 and give it the input it needs using **system()** or **exec()**?

I can get the key via google cloud API
the question is how to give it to a process that has already started?

Comment: if it accepts parameters then u can enter key with command

Comment: Do you control the code to "app1"?

Comment: Will app1 accept the key as a parameter? If not, you can use proc_open to interact with the process - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php